# correct usage of std::vector in dll interfaces (class with virtual destructor!)

Tags: c++, dll, virtual-destructor

I will try to explain my issue with an example.

I have the following class:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) class myclass
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    myclass() {};
    virtual ~myclass() {};
    // ~myclass() {};
};
```

*myclass* is used inside a **DLL**, that contains only the definition of the class *Test* (which is actually just an interface for the methods *foo1* and *foo2*):

```cpp
class Test
{
public:
    void                 foo1   (std::vector<myclass>& val);
    std::vector<myclass> foo2   ();
};

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) bool foo1(std::vector<myclass>& val)
    {
        val.clear();
        myclass tmp;
        val.push_back(tmp);
        val.push_back(tmp);
        val.push_back(tmp); //just an example!
        return true;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) std::vector<myclass> foo2()
    {
        std::vector<myclass> val;
        myclass tmp;
        val.push_back(tmp);
        val.push_back(tmp);
        val.push_back(tmp); //just an example!
        return val;
    }
}
```

The main application opens the DLL and calls the interface methods to obtain a vector filled by the methods *foo1* or *foo2*.

```cpp
typedef void                 (*FNPTR1)(std::vector<myclass>& val);
typedef std::vector<myclass> (*FNPTR2)();


int main()
{
    if (0)
    {
        HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\software\\mydll.dll");
        if (!hInst) { std::cout << "\nCould Not Load the Library";  return EXIT_FAILURE; }
        FNPTR1 fn = (FNPTR1)GetProcAddress(hInst, "foo1");
        if (!fn) { std::cout << "\nCould not locate the function";  return EXIT_FAILURE; }

        std::vector<myclass> tmp;
        fn(tmp);
        FreeLibrary(hInst);
        tmp.clear(); //crash here!
    }

    if (1)
    {
        HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\software\\mydll.dll");
        if (!hInst) { std::cout << "\nCould Not Load the Library";  return EXIT_FAILURE; }
        FNPTR2 fn = (FNPTR2)GetProcAddress(hInst, "foo2");
        if (!fn) { std::cout << "\nCould not locate the function";  return EXIT_FAILURE; }

        std::vector<myclass> tmp;
        tmp = fn();
        FreeLibrary(hInst);
        tmp.clear(); //crash here!
    }

    return 1;
}
}
```

Unfortunately, it happens that in both cases (using *foo1* or *foo2*), I get an *"Access violation reading XXXX"* error when I try to clear (or perform any other operation) on the *tmp* vector after unloading the dll.

**The issue happens only if the destructor of *myclass* is virtual**.

In my application, *myclass* is autogenerated and I'm not allowed to modify the destructor definition.
 However, I am free to modify the dll interface methods (i.e. foo1/foo2), if some solution exists at that level.

I'm also wondering if it is possible somehow to tell the system to use for the *tmp* vector the heap of the main program instead of the one used by the .dll.

I'm currently using Visual Studio c++ 2017 and I'm allowed to use C++11 standard (or later)

Thank you for your help.

---

Answering to the comments below:

- Yes, both the exe and the dll are compiled with the same toolchain. I'm using the /MD option. Please tell me if I should check additional stuff.
- Regarding the comment about the derivation of *myclass*, I tried also all the four possible combinations with a base class *myclassbase* and *myclass* derived from it:

  1- myclassbase with standard destructor and myclass with standard destructor -> ok

  2- myclassbase with standard destructor and myclass with virtual destructor -> crash

  3- myclassbase with virtual destructor and myclass with standard destructor -> crash

  4- myclassbase with virtual destructor and myclass with virtual destructor -> crash

  Hence I can conclude that the presence of just one virtual destructor is enough to generate the isssue.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem: don’t use stl in interface. What if your client uses a different stl implementation?

Comment: Is the main program and the dll built with exactly the same tool-chain and compilation options?

Comment: As far as I know the heap is the same. Otherwise you wouldn’t be able to allocate in dll and deallocate in exe.

Comment: _"...wouldn’t be able to allocate in dll and deallocate..."_: Which is exactly the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Is myclass inherited? If so, is the base class destructor pure? Did you forget to implement it?

Comment: Whether or not a DLL has it's own heap depends on whether you have a static or dynamic CRT (/MT or /MD). Still, C++ across DLL boundary is crap shoot; it's very fragile because there is no C++ ABI even between different VC++ minor versions. In addition to VC-version you have to match things like debug/release, shared/static CRT, unicode/MBCS, calling convention, exception handling mode (/EH), etc. Microsoft never does it this way, they use COM instead.

Comment: It is not clear if your base destructor is abstract or not. Some VC versions (I do not remember which) allows declaration of base pure destructor without implementation. I do not know if this is on purpose or not. If your base destructor is abstract, it should look like this: `virtual ~B() = 0 {}`.

Comment: @RichardCritten _”... exactly ...”_ - _”The issue happens only if the destructor of myclass is virtual.” :0)

Comment: @ZDF, no this is just an example. Anyway, the fact that myclass destructor is pure or not seems not relevant for this issue. I edited the original post to explain the fact that the crash happens also if I derive myclass from a class with a virtual destructor, meaning that I cannot use virtual destructors at all...

Answer (score 0):

I am, finally, in the front of a computer and had time to closely inspect your code.

1. `__declspec(dllexport) class myclass` is **wrong**. If you define it like this, both the DLL and EXE will expect an exported variable, but the DLL must see a `dllexport`ed class and the EXE must see a `dllimport`ed class.

   - To correctly export the class you should define a macro (see below) that it is interpreted as **export by the DLL** project and as **import by the EXE**.
   - The macro must be inserted **after `class` keyword**: `class TEST_API myclass`.
2. The same is valid for **exported functions**; only the export macro must be added before the return function type: `TEST_API inline bool foo1(std::vector<myclass>& val)`.
3. You will also have to add to the DLL project the **preprocessor definition that enables the export**: `Project Properties | Configuration Properties |Preprocessor | Preprocessor Definitions`: `TEST_EXPORTS`
4. Why did you add extern “C” and ignored the warnings? **Remove it**.
5. If your global functions are in the header file, don't forget to add **`inline`**.

*Now it should work.*

```
// mydll_exports.h
#pragma once

#ifdef TEST_EXPORTS
  #define TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #pragma comment(lib,"mydll.lib")
#endif
```